# orbeon pdf-url does not call the uri parameter

Tags: orbeon

Orbeon version "Orbeon Forms 4.6.1.201407102219 PE".

From my properties-local-dev.xml:

```
<!-- store acm form data (e.g. the form documents) by calling ACM services -->
<property as="xs:string"  
      name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.acm.*.data"
      value="acmRestServices"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI"  
      name="oxf.fr.persistence.acmRestServices.uri"
      value="http://localhost:8080/acm/api/v1/forms"/>
<property as="xs:boolean"  
      name="oxf.fr.persistence.acmRestServices.autosave"
      value="true"/> 
<property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.*.*"
  value='http://localhost:8080/acm/api/v1/forms/pdf?acm_ticket={//acm_ticket}'/>


<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-final.*.*">
   require-uploads
   then validate-all
   then save(query = "acm_ticket={//acm_ticket}")
   then send(content="pdf-url")
   then success-message("save-success")
   recover error-message("database-error")
 </property>
```

The PDF service (`http://localhost:8080/acm/api/v1/forms/pdf`) exists.  The crud services to save the form data work.  The acm_ticket field exists in the form.

The PDF service is never called.  Instead, in the orbeon.log, I see the exception below.  How can I get the PDF URL to work?  This problem will prevent us from using Orbeon.

`2014-08-07 16:16:59,692 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/acm/complaint-form/pdf/9ae097e8414e25a223edab3e1a935a9a45d99d39 - Received request
2014-08-07 16:16:59,885 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/persistence/crud/acm/complaint-form/form/form.xhtml - Received request
2014-08-07 16:16:59,915 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/oracle/crud/acm/complaint-form/form/form.xhtml - Received request
2014-08-07 16:16:59,944 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/oracle/crud/acm/complaint-form/form/form.xhtml - Timing: 29
2014-08-07 16:16:59,947 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/persistence/crud/acm/complaint-form/form/form.xhtml - Timing: 62
2014-08-07 16:16:59,961 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - not found {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "POST", path: "/fr/service/acm/complaint-form/pdf/9ae097e8414e25a223edab3e1a935a9a45d99d39", resource: "http://localhost:8888/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/acm/complaint-form/form/form.xhtml?document=9ae097e8414e25a223edab3e1a935a9a45d99d39"}
2014-08-07 16:16:59,962 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/acm/complaint-form/pdf/9ae097e8414e25a223edab3e1a935a9a45d99d39 - Timing: 270
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |xf:submission for submission id: fr-pdf-service-submission, error code received when submitting instance: 404         |
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |oxf:/apps/fr/includes/persistence/persistence-model.xml                           |processing submission response| 484|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |······················································································································|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,982 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |element=<xf:submission id="fr-pdf-service-submission" resource="/fr/service/{$app}/{$form}/pdf/{$document}?fr-language|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,983 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,986 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,987 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException                                                 |
2014-08-07 16:16:59,989 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,989 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|getReplacer                   |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 733|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  99|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  69|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.java           |  99|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission |connect                       |RegularSubmission.java        | 122|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|doSubmit                      |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 464|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|performDefaultAction          |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 296|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 137|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withEvent$1                   |Dispatch.scala                |  38|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |dispatchEvent                 |Dispatch.scala                |  72|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAPI$            |send                          |XFormsAPI.scala               | 261|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,990 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAPI$            |sendThrowOnError              |XFormsAPI.scala               | 278|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,991 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |s.FormRunnerActions$$anonfun$tryCreatePDFIfNeeded$1|apply                         |FormRunnerActions.scala       | 379|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,991 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |scala.util.Try$                                    |apply                         |Try.scala                     | 161|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,991 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.FormRunnerActions$class  |tryCreatePDFIfNeeded          |FormRunnerActions.scala       | 376|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,991 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.SimpleProcess$           |tryCreatePDFIfNeeded          |SimpleProcess.scala           |  34|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,991 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |oxf.fr.process.FormRunnerActions$$anonfun$trySend$1|apply                         |FormRunnerActions.scala       | 220|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,991 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |oxf.fr.process.FormRunnerActions$$anonfun$trySend$1|apply                         |FormRunnerActions.scala       | 180|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet                     |service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 727|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 303|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 208|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter        |doFilter                      |WsFilter.java                 |  52|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 241|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 208|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve      |invoke                        |StandardWrapperValve.java     | 220|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve      |invoke                        |StandardContextValve.java     | 122|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase|invoke                        |AuthenticatorBase.java        | 501|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 170|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve        |invoke                        |ErrorReportValve.java         |  98|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve          |invoke                        |AccessLogValve.java           | 950|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,993 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve       |invoke                        |StandardEngineValve.java      | 116|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 408|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor   |process                       |AbstractHttp11Processor.java  |1040|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |e.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler|process                       |AbstractProtocol.java         | 607|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor|run                           |JIoEndpoint.java              | 313|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor            |runWorker                     |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       |1145|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker     |run                           |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       | 615|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     |java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |Thread.java                   | 744|
2014-08-07 16:16:59,994 ERROR XFormsServer  -     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
2014-08-07 16:17:00,129 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Timing: 1049
2014-08-07 16:17:00,723 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Received request
2014-08-07 16:17:00,733 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Timing: 10`

Comment: I noticed that if I use the default Oracle provider to store form data, then the PDF URL **is** called. But, I really need to use my REST services to store the form data, **and** for the PDF URL to work...

Comment: Interesting; if you don't put that `send(content="pdf-url")` in the process (i.e. just persist the data through your own implementation of the API), are you getting any error in the log? Also can you try setting logging as described in this section: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-logging#TOC-Development-configuration? You should then get more information about the error in the log (and maybe you can put the relevant part on https://gist.github.com/ and link to the Gist here).

Comment: Avernet: when I leave off the send line, there are no errors in the log.  My custom REST service is called correctly.  With the send line, my custom REST service is still called correctly, but there is no call to the PDF URL.  I updated the log config.  The new log output is much longer.  Gist URL:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e5d2a6f1dcc206c3fa8.

Comment: OK, so it's getting a 404 with the URL `http://localhost:8888/orbeon/fr/service/acm/complaint-form/pdf/f84ff554d2d0313f8fcdb8137546a55b79574051`. Not sure why this would be happening; I'll have to look into this in more details.

Comment: When the `POST` request is made to `http://localhost:8888/orbeon/fr/service/acm/complaint-form/pdf/f84ff554d2d0313f‌​8fcdb8137546a55b79574051`, this service will retrieve the source of the form, and I suspect that there is a problem with that. Could you try using Charles, setting up Orbeon Forms to go through Charles (more on this at http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/04/let-charles-help-you-monitor-http.html). Looking at the log, do you see a problem with the calls to your implementation of the persistence API?

Comment: Avernet: the URL `http://localhost:8888/orbeon/fr/service/acm/complaint-form/pdf/f84ff554d2d0313f‌​‌​8fcdb8137546a55b79574051` is an Orbeon URL, over which we have no control.  Our application's access log shows no calls to our application.  Since there is no record in the access log, that indicates to me that Orbeon is not calling our application.  If it was, we could implement a service to retrieve the form data.  But it seems to me Orbeon is not calling our application at all.

Comment: It's possible, but hard to check on my side since I don't have your implementation of the persistence API, and the issue doesn't happen with the out-of-the-box implementation. So I am left suspecting that something is different with your implementation. To figure what it is, I think the simplest way is to look at all the HTTP requests with a Charles (or similar), and compare the case that's working with the one that isn't. And I'm sorry if I can't help more on this. If you get a chance to do this, you'll let me know if you find something comparing the HTTP requests.

Comment: @avernet: To test on your side, just setup a custom REST service, store the form definition in Oracle (or some other database), and store the form data via the custom REST service.  The Charles monitor clearly shows the custom REST service is never even called.  Charles screen shot: [http://oi58.tinypic.com/i1fr82.jpg](http://oi58.tinypic.com/i1fr82.jpg).  I asked my programmer for a log file, and for another log file showing the working PDF URL (by changing form persistence to Oracle, instead of the custom service).  Will post it soon.

Comment: @avernet: is it required for the form data storage and form definition storage to use the same persistence mechanism?  From the documentation it seemed like we could use a JDBC data source for the form definitions, and a custom REST service for the form data.

Comment: @avernet: since the custom REST service is never called, it makes me think either our configuration is incomplete (so Orbeon doesn't know how to call us), or there is some Orbeon issue.  Actually, we're hoping for the next release to resolve this issue by just sending us the PDF along with the form data XML.  But in the meantime we'd still like to solve this issue.

Comment: @avernet: here is our configuration to store the form: [https://gist.github.com/david-oc-miller/49a9b40d5ae20b3c6196](https://gist.github.com/david-oc-miller/49a9b40d5ae20b3c6196)

Comment: @avernet: we now two sets of Charles output and HTTP access log output (from the REST service application).  The first set shows what happens when form data is stored in Oracle: Orbeon successfully calls the PDF URL.  The second set shows what happens when form data is stored via our REST service: the PDF URL is never called.  Gist for Set 1 (form data in Oracle, PDF URL is called): https://gist.github.com/david-oc-miller/ba6fdbbb8e0200cb6988.  Gist for Set 2 (form data via REST service, PDF URL is not called): https://gist.github.com/david-oc-miller/df40d943e6c71e047d20.

Comment: The form data and form definition don't have to use the same implementation of the persistence API. You can even have forms in different apps (or even different individual forms) use different implementation of the persistence API.

Comment: About sending the PDF binary instead of just a "callback URL", yes, we're also hoping to be able to support this for 4.7. For reference, the issue is https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1835. Right now, if you have authentication on your side, the current `send(content = "pdf-url")` is very inconvenient as it requires the service calling the URL to also pass the `JSESSIONID` in its request.

Comment: I looked at the Charles log, but both logs only show requests to `/orbeon/xforms-server` (plus some other unrelated traffic). For the requests made by Orbeon Forms to also go through Charles, you need to add the following 2 properties: `<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.http.proxy.host" value="localhost"/>
<property as="xs:integer" name="oxf.http.proxy.port" value="8888"/>`. Could you try to recapture this with those properties set?